# php M or F (male or female)

Tags: php

I know there are more elegant ways to set up an html form to take the input of male or female; however, I am learning, and I was just wondering if this is also possible:

```
//Incorporate two checks
 if (empty($_POST['sex'])==FALSE && sanityCheck($_POST['sex'], 'string', 1)==TRUE)
      {
      // if the checks are ok for  sex we assign sex  to a variable
      $sex = $_POST['sex'];
       }
      else
      {
      // if all is not well we echo an error message
      echo 'Please enter a valid Gender';
      // and exit the script
      exit();
      }
```

If so, how would I check this with regex?
Whether the user typed M or F.

I am thinking:

```
function checksex($sexcheck)
{
//Some regex here to check the sex?
  return preg_match('               ', $sexcheck);
}
```

And then call checksex as a third check added to the if conditional, like this:

```
if (empty($_POST['sex'])==FALSE && sanityCheck($_POST['sex'], 'string', 1) != FALSE && checksex($_POST['sex'], 1) ==TRUE)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a regular expression to check for one out of two possible strings??? "if" is just fine for that. If you are looking to reduce the sanity check, the $_POST fiddling and the error message, regular expressions won't help you. They are merely a tool to find patterns in strings.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I might just leave as is, since I was just playing around with regex.

Comment: `empty(...)==TRUE` is exactly identical to `empty(...)` as `empty` can only return `true` or `false`.

Comment: Okay, so you saying empty can be either true or false, so there is no need for ==TRUE, is that correct?

Comment: You should never check for `== FALSE` or ` == TRUE`. The `if` in PHP knows how to check for true-ness. The problem is that there are many true values and just a few false ones. For example: "hello world" is also a true values in PHP, but 0 is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check if the user typed M or F, all you would need to do is a string comparison. No need for regex

```
if ( isset($_POST['sex']) ){
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    if ( $sex == 'M' ){
        echo 'Male';
    }else if ( $sex == 'F' ){
        echo 'Female';
    }else{
        echo 'Please enter a valid Gender';
    }
}else{
    echo 'Please enter a valid Gender';
}
```

However, rather than having the user type out M or F, why not use a [select box](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_Select.asp) or Radio Buttons ?

A select box may look something like this

```
<select name='sex'>
    <option selected="yes" value="NA">Not Saying</option>
    <option value="F">Female</option>
    <option value="M">Male</option>
 </select>
```

Or radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="M" /> Male <br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="F" /> Female
```

You would of course still have to check that `$_POST['sex']` is still M or F, and handle the case where it isn't either of them, as the user may decide to post an invalid value.

Answer (score 4):

Try this "(M|F){1}"   without the quotes

Comment: Thanks but  Pekka Gaiser, just pointed out that there is no need for a  regular expression to check for one out of two possible strings.
Nevertheless, that's good to know, thank you.

Comment: It's much much better than using huge 'else if' clause!!

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
// check if the sex variable is 'f' or 'm'
        $sex = ($_POST['sex'] == 'f' || $_POST['sex'] == 'm') ? $_POST['sex'] : false;
// thanks to peter
    // if $sex is false then echo..
        if (!$sex)
            echo ('Please enter a valid Gender');
```

Explaination

its a conditional operator called Ternary Operator. Its like

(if clause) ? (then) : (else);

Or

(expr 1) ? (expr 2) : (expr 3);

expr 2 is evaluated if expr 1 is true
expr 3 is evaluated if expr 1 is false

Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: What's the function of ? before the variable $sex=$POST['sex']

And whats : after the variable?

Your techniques are advanced..., but the code is simple.

Comment: You used the ternary operator in the wrong way. Don't use assignment in the second or third expression. As this will create many subtle bugs. Use something like `$sex = .... ? $_POST['sex'] : false`.

Comment: actually i always use ternary operator that way.. thanks for telling.. i guess I have to change many scripts of mine now lol

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = $_POST['sex'];

if(isset($s) && $s == 'M') {
    $sex = "Male";
} elseif(isset($s) && $s == 'F') {
    $sex = "Female";
} else {
    $sex = "Please enter a valid gender";
}
```